# primefaces datatable losing connection with the respective object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, I have a nested datatable using rowExpansion on primefaces, in each line of the child datatable I have a button to edit the content, the problem is that when I have more than one occurence on father datatable, the occurences on child table loose the connection with the object, so when I click on button edit the reference is wrong.

the table:

```
p:dataTable value="#{LiquidacaoControl.liquidacoes}" var="liquidacao" id="tbl_liquidacao" emptyMessage="Nenhuma liquidação adicionada" rendered="#{LiquidacaoControl.empenho != null}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Tabela de Liquidações" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{LiquidacaoControl.onRowExpandir}" update="tbl_documentoFiscal" />
        <p:column>
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Data">
            <h:outputText value="#{liquidacao.data}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Valor da liquidação">
            <h:outputText value="#{liquidacao.totalValorLiquidacao}">
                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Valor retido">
            <h:outputText value="#{liquidacao.valorTotalRetido}">
                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="tipo">
            <h:outputText value="#{liquidacao.tipo.descricao}">
                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" oncomplete="liquidacao_dialog.show();" update=":formCorpo:liquidacaoForm">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{liquidacao}" target="#{LiquidacaoControl.liquidacao}" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" update=":formCorpo:tbl_liquidacao" actionListener="#{LiquidacaoControl.excluirLiquidacao}">
                <f:attribute name="liquidacao" value="#{liquidacao}"></f:attribute>
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Adicionar documento fiscal" update=":formCorpo:documentoFiscalForm" action="#{LiquidacaoControl.novoDocumentoFiscal}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{liquidacao}" target="#{LiquidacaoControl.liquidacao}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>

            <p:dataTable value="#{LiquidacaoControl.documentosFiscais}" rowKey="#{documentoFiscal.hash}" selectionMode="single" var="documentoFiscal" id="tbl_documentoFiscal" emptyMessage="Nenhum Documento Fiscal">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":formCorpo:tbl_retencao" oncomplete="tbl_retencao_dialog.show();" listener="#{LiquidacaoControl.onRowSelection}" />

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Tabela de documentos fiscais" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="N° Doc">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoFiscal.numero}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Chave NF-e">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoFiscal.chaveAcesso}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Data emissão">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoFiscal.dataEmissao}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Valor">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoFiscal.valor}">
                        <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Valor retido">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoFiscal.valorTotalRetido}">
                        <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="R$" type="currency" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":formCorpo:documentoFiscalForm" actionListener="#{LiquidacaoControl.editarDocumentoFiscal}">
                        <f:attribute name="documentoFiscal" value="#{documentoFiscal}"></f:attribute>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" update=":formCorpo:tbl_liquidacao" actionListener="#{LiquidacaoControl.excluirDocumentoFiscal}">
                        <f:attribute name="documentoFiscal" value="#{documentoFiscal}"></f:attribute>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Adicionar retenção" onclick="retencao_dialog.show();" actionListener="#{LiquidacaoControl.novaRetencao}" update=":formCorpo:retencaoForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{documentoFiscal}" target="#{LiquidacaoControl.documentoFiscal}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
```

the methods:

```
    public void editarDocumentoFiscal(ActionEvent event) {
    DocumentoFiscal pDocumentoFiscal = (DocumentoFiscal) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("documentoFiscal");
    setDocumentoFiscal(pDocumentoFiscal);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("documentoFiscal_dialog.show()");
}

    public void excluirDocumentoFiscal(ActionEvent event) {
    DocumentoFiscal pDocumentoFiscal = (DocumentoFiscal) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("documentoFiscal");
    encontrarPaiDocumentoFiscal(pDocumentoFiscal);
    liquidacao.getDocumentosFiscais().remove(pDocumentoFiscal);
}
    public void onRowExpandir(ToggleEvent event) {
    documentosFiscais = new DocumentoFiscalModel(((Liquidacao) event.getData()).getDocumentosFiscais());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formCorpo:tbl_documentoFiscal");
}
```

That's it thanks in advance.

Comment: No offense but nesting datatables sounds scary. If your requirement doesn't really needs such an implementation, you better use `ui:repeat` as a repeator.

Comment: I know, but is necessary for me to use that implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the client state in jsf, it's works for my

web.xml add

```
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```